# Bottom sheet dialog fragment

Tags: java, android

Called from **MapFragment**

```
ScheduleFragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
scheduleFragment.showNow(getChildFragmentManager(),scheduleFragment.getTag());
```

**ScheduleFragment**

```
public class ScheduleFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

public ScheduleFragment(){

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);
    return view;
}

}
```

Now the problem I am facing is whenever the app is resumed the modal bottomsheet appears to be changing state from hidden to expanded is there any fix for this?